# Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver Spring Boot Parent 2.3.0

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here is my pom.xml

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        2.3.0.RELEASE</version>  -->
        2.3.0.RELEASE
         
    
    com.cab.booking
    cab-booking
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    cab-booking
    Cab Booking Platform

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my application.properties file

[image]

Tried using postgresql version 42.2.12 but no luck.

Here is error log screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Remove driver-class-name and use proper dialect

Answer (score 0):

May be this doesn't make sense but I had same problem and it was fixed with this 2 lines:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```